# How to make similar values in a column equal

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Student_ID   Subject       Class_Feedback_question    Class_Feedback_Answer
100101       Physics       How was physics class?     Excellent: 5 
100101       Physics       how was physics class:     very good:4  
100101       Physics       How was the Presentation:  Good: 3  
100101       Chemistry     How Much would you rate?   Excellent: 5 
100102       Math          how much would you rate:   Excellent: 4
100102       Physics       how was presentation:      Good: 3
```

I want to make the similar row values in `Class_Feedback_question` column look equal, (e.g: making `:` as `?` at end of questions `or` keeping one question as constant and replace the other similar questions with that, e.g: `how was presentation:` is replaced by  `How was the Presentation:` )
something like this:

```
Student_ID   Subject       Class_Feedback_question     Class_Feedback_Answer
100101       Physics       How was physics class?      Excellent: 5 
100101       Physics       How was physics class?      very good:4  
100101       Physics       How was the presentation:   Good: 3  
100101       Chemistry     How Much would you rate?    Excellent: 5 
100102       Math          How much would you rate?    Excellent: 4
100102       Physics       How was the presentation:   Good: 3
```

How can this be done in `python Pandas`?
**Also**, How can I create pivot table based on `Class_Feedback_Answer`?

Answer (score 0):

To replace ':' by '?' you can use the `apply` method

```py
df['Class_Feedback_question'] = df['Class_Feedback_question'].apply(x: x.replace(':', '?'))
```

and to rephrase questions you'll have to do it case by case, I would suggest using the `map` method

```py
rephrasing = {'how was presentation': 'How was the presentation'}
df['Class_Feedback_question'] = df['Class_Feedback_question'].map(rephrasing)
```

For the pivot table please check pandas documentation because you are not giving enough information. It's really clear: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html?highlight=pivot#pandas.DataFrame.pivot